# Retrieving data from polar accesslink via php sdk

Tags: php

I am attempting to use the polar php sdk to retrieve data from the polar accesslink api. I am able to get through the Oauth2 workflow but am stuck after receiving the access token. Following the documentation I am attempting to register a user using the following code:

```
    $config = Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setAccessToken($this->token);

    $apiInstance = new UsersApi(
        // If you want use custom http client, pass your client which implements `GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface`.
        // This is optional, `GuzzleHttp\Client` will be used as default.
        new \GuzzleHttp\Client(),
        $config
    );

    $body = new Register(); // \Coachbox\Services\Polar\Models\Register | 
    try {
        $result = $apiInstance->registerUser($body);
        print_r($result);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Exception when calling UsersApi->registerUser: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
    }
```

However the sdk throws the following error: [400] Client error: `POST https://www.polaraccesslink.com/v3/users` resulted in a `400 Bad Request`

If instead use a curl command as follows (but through php):

```
curl -X POST https://www.polaraccesslink.com/v3/users \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer {access-token}'

Body parameter

{
  "member-id": "User_id_999"
}
```

I get an empty response. I feel I must be missing an important step, but I do not know what it is. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: 
Heard back from Polar Support, there is an error in their API documentation. The -H 'Content-type' should be 'application/json'. But, if I make the change I get a new error:

"Unrecognized token 'member': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream); line: 1, column: 8]"

EDIT 2: I was able to get the code working through a cURL request (I didn't have my body formatted as json properly). However, I am still unable to get the sdk working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a bit of debugging on the same issue and it turns out the SDK example misses the vital step of setting the member_id

It should be:

```
$body = new Register();
$body->setMemberId($your_member_id);
```